# How to get the smallest texel that wraps a triangle

Tags: opengl, glsl

Assume I have the UVs of the three vertices of a triangle. What is the fastest way to get the smallest texel that wraps this triangle? That is, the mip level and the UV coordinates of this texel.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Let us use the following notation:

- Let `p` be the index of your points in the triangle, so `p in {0,1,2}`
- Let `n(p)` be a 2D vector function representing the *normalized* texcoords in `[0,1]` (per component), assigned to point index `p`
- Let `t(p,l)` nbe the *unnormalized* tex coords assiged to point p for mipmap level `l`

This means `t(p,l) = n(p) * vec2(width(l), height(l))`.

If we want to find the mipmap level, we can do this by calculating the size of the triangle in the base level `t(p,0)`:

Let:

- `a = t(1,0) - t(0,0)`
- `b = t(2,0) - t(0,0)`
  `a` and `b` represent the vectors of the edges of the triangle in texture space, at the base level. So let's find the maximum individually for each dimension:
- `x_max = max(a.x,b.x)`
- `y_max = max(a.y,b.y)`

These two basically describe the size of an axis-aligned bounding-box around our triangle. So we can use the longest side to find the mipmap level:

- `m = max(x_max,y_max)`.

Finding the right mipmap level means finding the level `l` for which the size `m` would be `<= 1` texel. By going up one mip level, the value of `m` would be halved. so we get (with the appropriate rounding):

- `l = floor(log2(ceil(m)))`

What we have now is the level where the size of the triangle would fit in one texel. This is the *lower bound* of the actual level that fullfills your criteria. The triangle might intersect up to 2x2 texels at level n. However, just going up one more level might not do the trick, as it might still intersect different texel in the upper-next level. In the worst case, your triangle encloses the center point of your texture, in which case, only the upmost mip level sized 1x1 will ever completely enclose your triangle completely.

So a naive algorithm could be

1. start at level `l` as calculated above above
2. calculate `floor(t(p,l))` for all three points
3. Compare them. If the are all identical, you are finished, `l` is the result. If not all three are identical, increase `l` by one and repeat at step 2.

The resulting `l` will be the level you searched for.

> and the UV coordinates of this texel

A texel doesn't have one UV coordinate, but represents a rectangle in UV space. So it is not clear what you want, but you might want some of the following

- the unnormalized integer texel coords, which are just the`floor(t(p,l))` you already calculated
- the unnormalized coordinates of the texel center, which is just `floor(t(p,l)) + vec2(0.5)`
- the unnormalized coordinates of the barycenter of the triangle, which is just `(t(0,l) + t(1,l) + t(2,l))/3.0`
- the normalized variant of any of the above, which is just the value divided by the size of level `l`